# How to move several divs up the DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to move several divs up the DOM with jQuery.

```
<section>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="temps"></div>
    <div class="list"></div>
</section>
```

I would like to move all the .list divs after the .title div.  How can I do this with jQuery.

This `$('.temps').insertAfter('.title');` does not work, it places all the .list after the first .title

Comment: Do you mean `$('.list').insertAfter('.title');`? As that should be working fine; demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m2rpxcjq/

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to move all the .list divs after the .title div.

You can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each) method like this:

```js
    $('.list').each(function(){
       $(this).insertAfter(
          $(this) //.list div
            .closest('section') //find parent div section
            .find('.title') //find child div
        );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="temps">temps</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="temps">temps</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="title">title</div>
    <div class="temps">temps</div>
    <div class="list">list</div>
</section>
```

Comment: this did not work for me but in the end I got it working with `parent()` rather than `closest()`

Comment: That's why I was commenting in my post saying find parent, Your html may be varied so...anyway at the end, you solved it. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

simply try this, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/bndez2no/)

```
$('.list').insertAfter($('.title'));
```

or

```
$('.list').insertAfter('.title'); //only selector no object
```

Comment: Note that `insertAfter` can take a string selector, so you don't need to create another jQuery object: `.insertAfter('.title');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.list').each(function(){
   $(this).prevAll('.title').after($(this));
});
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal sory prevAll

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't of been anble to get this working without @Bhojendra Nepal help in his answer above, and while his solution worked in his code snippit it did not work on my application.  In the end the below worked for me.

```
jQuery('.list').each(function(){
   jQuery(this).insertAfter(jQuery(this).parent().find('.title'));
});
```